# Setting a var I can use as an environment-var/macro in MSVC++ 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I want to set a variable in my project config that can then be used elsewhere in the config the same way as an environment var, or built-in Macro value like $(OutDir), etc.

I thought this was the way to do it:
[image]

But when I use $(ConfigurationSuffix) in my post-build step (I want to set single rule to cope with myapp.exe Vs myapp_d.exe) I get an error the var doesn't exist.

Is what I want possible? And if so what did I do wrong?

Comment: You'll have to create the macro first.  View + Other Windows + Property Manager.  Add a new project property sheet.  Press F1 to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you've done is set a variable for use *when debugging* - not when building.

To do what you want, try:

- Open your solution in VS2008, go to `View -> Property Manager`
- In the Property Manager, select your project
- Select all the debug configurations (using Ctrl+click)

  - Right click on your multiple selection, `Add New Project Property Sheet...`, call it `dbgprops` or similar
  - Double click any of the `dbgprops`
  - Go to `User Macros`, click `Add Macro`
  - Enter the name and value as `ConfigurationSuffix` and `_d`
  - Tick `Set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment`
- Select all the Release configurations and do similarly, calling the sheet relprops, and leaving Value blank instead of "_d"

Now try `$(ConfigurationSuffix)` from your build events!